# Hangman: if correct button clicked application hangs

Tags: java

In my hangman application I've created a set of buttons for the user, and then the word being guessed in hangman app is randomly selected from a file... The word is printed using an JLabel... But as soon as a button is clicked the application freezes. Can anyone please tell my this is happening...

---

## How I created the buttons

```
for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++){
    String buttonText = new Character(i).toString();
    JButton button = getButton(buttonText);
    panel1.add(button);
}
```

---

## button ActionListener

```
public JButton getButton(final String text){
    final JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(original.toUpperCase().indexOf(button.getText())!=-1){
                guessString = text;
                guessLetter = guessString.charAt(0);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(secret);
                while(error < 6){
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++){
                    if (original.charAt(i) == guessLetter){
                        builder.setCharAt(i, guessLetter);
                    }
                }
                secret = builder.toString();
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no " + text );
                error++;
                if(error >= 0) imageName = "hangman1.jpg";
                if(error >= 1) imageName = "hangman2.jpg";
                if(error >= 2) imageName = "hangman3.jpg";
                if(error >= 3) imageName = "hangman4.jpg";
                if(error >= 4) imageName = "hangman5.jpg";
                if(error >= 5) imageName = "hangman6.jpg";
                if(error >= 7) imageName = "hangman7.jpg"; 
            }
        }
    });
    return button;
}
```

Comment: More hangman tips [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12024012/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in `actionPerformed` if `error` is less than 6.

```
while(error < 6) {
}
```

Comment: Even if I take out the loop, the buttons doesnt do anything, or rather the JLabel doesnt change

Comment: What is expected to happen when you click a button? You are assigning a string to the `secret` variable, are you updating anything with it? I don't see anything updating a `JLabel` in your code.

Comment: When a button is clicked and if the letter IS in the word, the string builder builds a new string, thus giving the impression that the letter unhides if guessed correct... and what do you mean by anything updating the label?

Comment: @user1614977 How would the label know that something changed if you don't tell the label?

Comment: @user1614977: But you want to show that new string in the `JLabel`, correct?

Comment: Yes, fair enough didn't think of that, will see how to do that, thanks

Comment: If you have already created the `JLabel`, just use the `setText` method to update its text.

Comment: Thanks, finally got it to work :) been searching for this code for more than 2 weeks