# read JPanel content

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

Is it possible to read the content of a `JPanel`?

In my situation, I've got a main JPanel that I called *`container`*, and 3 other JPanels inside it: *`p1`*, *`p2`* and *`p3`*.
I've also created a class that `extends JPanel` for a little virtual keyboard (26 buttons) and this implements `ActionListener`.

The *`p1`* is to display the title of the game, *`p2`* is the virtual keyboard and *`p3`* should display the value of the button I clicked on.

My class *`VirtualKeyboard`* has a constructor that accepts an object of type `JPanel` (to get the container and hopefully its contents).

Many thanks for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "read"?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable (as edit) and better to add more detailed descriptions,

Comment: for what reason do you want to "read" the content? (maybe there is an other solution for it, you did not thought about)

Comment: Technically, yes, but not a practical approach. See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12023334/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out  [`JPanel#getComponent(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponent%28int%29) to access the members that have been added to a `Container`(JPanel is implementing Container).