# where to put methods in java swing gui generated program and adding "controller"

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

im super confused about how to add the controller stuff to java Swing gui
1) the code is auto generated and untouchable
when i drag and drop the components into the gui a massive thing called initcomponents() is auto generated
-this initcomponents() is called in the constructor and part of this includes a pack(), now correct me if im wrong but this means the deal is sealed? things are now packed and cant be modified?
-but how do i automatically change the text of labels? so i have a method that generates a string, is there anyway to do variableName.setText(stringMethod)? where do i call it? i cant call it in constructor because of untouchable initcomponents()
-where am i suppose to put all the meat of program? in constructor? or in method and then call method in constructor? i cant call any methods in constructor because of untouchable auto generated thing.

i am so confused - spent 100+ hours on this hangman thing

heres code:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
protected static final Insets   bottomInsets    = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
protected static final Insets   normalInsets    = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
protected static final Insets   spacingInsets   = new Insets(20, 10, 0, 10);
private int                     wordGridy;
public static int     maximumWrongGuesses =7;
HangmanModel model;
private List<String>          word;
private List<JLabel>          wordText;
private JPanel                  outsidePanel;
private JPanel                  panel;
/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    //this.frame = frame


    initComponents();
    tryingToControl();



}
public void tryingToControl(){
    lettersUsedText.setText(model.getNumberOfGuesses());
}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    Gallows gallows = new Gallows();
    Figure figure = new Figure();

    Color color1 = Color.BLUE;
    Color color2 = Color.BLUE;
    g.setColor(color1);
    gallows.paintComponent(g);


    switch (7) {
    case 7:
        color2 = Color.red;
        figure.drawNoose(g, color2);
    case 6:
        figure.drawRightLeg(g, color2);
    case 5:
        figure.drawLeftLeg(g, color2);
    case 4:
        figure.drawRightArm(g, color2);
    case 3:
        figure.drawLeftArm(g, color2);
    case 2:
        figure.drawBody(g, color2);
    case 1:
        figure.drawHead(g, color2);
    }

}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    secretWordTitle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    secretWordText = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lettersUsedTitle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lettersUsedText = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    guessTitle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    guessTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    secretWordTitle.setText("Secret Word:");

    secretWordText.setText("?????????????");

    lettersUsedTitle.setText("Letters Used:");

    lettersUsedText.setText(model.getUnguessedLetters());

    guessTitle.setText("Enter a guess:");

    guessTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            guessTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Guess");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Reset Game");

    jButton3.setText("Custom Word");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(47, 47, 47)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(guessTitle)
                        .addComponent(secretWordTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(lettersUsedTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(secretWordText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(lettersUsedText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(guessTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jButton1))))
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addContainerGap(79, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(401, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(secretWordTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(secretWordText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lettersUsedTitle)
                .addComponent(lettersUsedText))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(guessTitle)
                .addComponent(guessTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addGap(30, 30, 30))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void guessTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     secretWordText.setText("guess");   


}                                        


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField guessTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel guessTitle;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel lettersUsedText;
private javax.swing.JLabel lettersUsedTitle;
private javax.swing.JLabel secretWordText;
private javax.swing.JLabel secretWordTitle;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: if you want to have full flexibility you probably need to code your components. It's a trade off you need to consider. From my personal experience, it's better to code your GUI rather than using your IDE drag'n'drop features, but again it is my personal experience.

Comment: what ide are you using and can you provide some code please? Its hard to give hints how to accesx sth if you cant see the environment.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12023334/230513).